# how to avoid scrolling to the TEXTFORMFIELD when I force input value to that field in flutter

Tags: forms, flutter, dart, layout, flutter-layout

I have two text form fields that change same value on the same screen in flutter (to make it easier on the user), the user can change the variable from any of the two fields.

The problem is that when the user changes the value in one field (and while still inputting) flutter automatically scrolls to the second field, and even worse the animation is unpredictable sometimes it scrolls back to the original field and sometimes it keeps the view to the second field.

What I need is to make flutter ignore this animation. I want the user to change the value of the text field as a normal iput and in the background flutter would change
the second field, so that is the use of scroll down at some point to the second field he will find the variable updated.

```
CustomTextFormFieldRow(
                        maxLength: 5,
                        suffixText: 'in',
                        labelText: 'Annular Diam.',
                        maxInput: kMaxHoleSize,
                        minInput: _casing.iDiameter(),
                        controller: _controller1,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          if (value.isNotEmpty &&
                              value != '.' &&
                              double.tryParse(value) != null) {
                            _annularOD = double.tryParse(value);
                            _controller2.text = value;
                          } else {
                            _annularOD = 0;
                          }
                          setState(() {
                            _annularOD;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
```

Here I have a custom form field that I have created, I have created two of those on my screen each having its own controller named one and two, when the user input value add any of them I setState() and change the value of the other controller with `_controller2.text = value;`

Answer (score 0):

check your controller looks like you have provided the same controller to both text form field.

Comment: no .. not the same, I have 2 controllers .. the text changes but it looks like flutter has an automatic function that shifts focus to TEXTFORMFIELD once changed .. just a guess